# Every metric space $R$ has a unique completion such that $\phi(x)=x$ for $x\in R$. (Kolmogorov and Fomin)

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I am reading a famous book by Kolmogorov and Fomin.

> Definition:
> Given a metric space $R$ with closure $[R]$, a complete metric space $R^*$ is called a **completion** of $R$ if $R\subset R^*$ and $[R]=R^*$, i.e., if $R$ is a subset of $R^*$ everywhere dense in $R^*$.

There is the following theorem in this book:

[image]

The authors wrote:

1. The points of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ also belong to $R^{**}$, where they form a fundamental sequence (why?).
2. It is clear that $x^{**}$ is independent of the choice of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to the point $x^*$ (why?).

Are my proofs of these facts right?

> proof of 1.:
> Since $x_n\to x^*$, $|x_{n'}-x_{n^{''}}|\leq |x_{n'}-x^*|+|x_{n^{''}}-x^*|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$ for $n^{'}\ge N$ and $n^{''}\ge N$, where $N$ is some natural number.
> So, $\{x_n\}$ is a fundamental sequence in $R^*$ and $R^{**}$.

> proof of 2.:
> Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{x^{'}_n\}$ be two sequences which converge to the point $x^*$.
> Let $\{x^{''}_n\}$ be a sequence such that $x^{''}_n=x_{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ if $n$ is odd and $x^{''}_n=x^{'}_{\frac{n}{2}}$ if $n$ is even.
> Then, $x^{''}_n\to x^*$.
> So, $\{x^{''}_n\}$ is a fundamental sequence in $R^*$ and $R^{**}$.
> So, $\{x^{''}_n\}$ converges to some point $x^{**}$ in $R^{**}$.
> Since $x^{''}_{2n-1}=x_n$ and $x^{''}_{2n}=x^{'}_n$, $\{x_n\}$ and $\{x^{'}_n\}$ are subsequences of $\{x^{''}_n\}$.
> So, $x_n\to x^{**}$ and $x^{'}_n\to x^{**}$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The first one is a standard useful fact: every convergent sequence is Cauchy (or in your terms fundamental).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: You’re welcome.